# LoadError: cannot load such file -- tiny_tds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tiny-tds

I have been troubleshooting a problem in my Ruby on Rails application on windows system. when i try to run server rails s i got error..

**Rails log**

**bundle exec rails s**

**Error**

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.1-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:46:in `require': cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/tiny_tds (LoadError)

Comment: did you install the devkit as per the instructions in `tiny_tds` gem docs?

"If you use Windows, we pre-compile TinyTDS with static versions of FreeTDS and supporting libraries. If you're using RubyInstaller the binary gem will require that devkit is installed and in your path to operate properly."